# Change color textview in adapter spinner android

Tags: android, colors, textview, spinner

```
  reports = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_report);
  reportType = getIntent().getStringExtra("report");

   private void setTypeReport(){
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.type_report, R.layout.item_spinner_p);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    reports.setAdapter(adapter);

    int pos= adapter.getPosition(reportType);
    type_report= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.type_report);

    String valueAtIndex = type_report[pos];
    for(int i = pos; i > 0; i--){
        type_report[i] = type_report[i-1];
    }
    type_report[0] = valueAtIndex;
    //now set this array to second Spinner
    ArrayAdapter spinnerBArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            type_report);
    reports.setAdapter(spinnerBArrayAdapter);
    newreport = reports.getSelectedItem().toString();
}
               main.xml
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
               <RelativeLayout
               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:background="#eee"
               android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
               android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">

                 <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_report"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_box"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                </Spinner>
               </RelattiveLayout>


     item_spinner_p.xml 

     <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@android:id/text1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="@color/black"
       android:textSize="17sp"
       android:paddingTop="10dp"
       android:paddingBottom="10dp"
       android:paddingLeft="7dp"
       android:paddingRight="7dp"/>



      string.xml
<string-array name="type_report">
    <item>Male</item>
    <item>Female</item>

</string-array>
```

Default color is black in item_spinner_p.xml ... either male or female , it will show black color.. Problem is , I want to do when reportType = Male (from previous activity), it will change color to Red and if reportType = Female (from previous activity) , it change color to Blue.

I think to use way set color in string.xml .. set color Red for Male .. but i dont know correct way to set it ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom spinner adapter. Look at this page for how to do that: http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286

But if you want simple solution you can create two separate layouts for male and females like this :

For males: item_males

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/text1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="@android:color/red"
   android:textSize="17sp"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:paddingLeft="7dp"
   android:paddingRight="7dp"/>
```

And for females: item_females

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/text1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="@android:color/blue"
   android:textSize="17sp"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:paddingLeft="7dp"
   android:paddingRight="7dp"/>
```

With text colors set to red and blue for males and females respectively. Then apply a check while setting the adapter like this :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
if(reportType.equals("Males")){
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.type_report, R.layout.item_males);}
else{
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.type_report, R.layout.item_females);}
```

Comment: your answer is correct but to customize with my code , it never change color .. maybe i do replace spinner ..(in my code) Really tired to customize it .. Can we set automatically color in item at string-array .. ?

Comment: No, we can't define colors for string items. You have to manually set it via either of the methods i mentioned.

Comment: Alright Sir .. In my code , i used two ArrayAdapter which is adapter and simpleBArrayAdapter .. I do this coz when user select Female , it will change position to display female .. so need to used new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,type_report); .. it different with ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.type_report, R.layout.item_females);} ...

Comment: when i change to for simpleBArrayAdapter to ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.type_report, R.layout.item_females);} , it success to change color but it show Male first even user select Female

Comment: For moving your spinner to selected item when you set the adapter use reports.setSelection(0) for males or reports.setSelection(1) for females after you set your adapter.

Comment: Can you show the code .. Really blur coz spend one day to find the solution .. huhu

Comment: after reports.setAdapter(adapter);
insert these lines -> 
if(reportType.equals("Males"))
reports.setSelection(0);
else
reports.setSelection(1);

Comment: Ok thank Sir .. Already done .. I do  
int pos= adapter.getPosition(reportType);  reports.setSelection(pos);

Comment: Sir .. can we do one layout ? textview for male and female in one xml file ? then get id textview .. ?